# Any difference between angular $inject property and inline array annotation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, inject

Reading [angular docs on dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), there are two minification-friendly methods to do this:

- Inline Array Annotation:

  `module.factory("MyStuff",['dependency',function(dep){...}])`
- The `$inject` property:

  `function MyStuff(dep) {...}
  MyStuff.$inject = ['dependency'];
  module.factory("MyStuff",MyStuff);`

The inline one (first) is recommended. In one of my projects the style guide insists on the use of `$inject` property. I also see `$inject` property form quite often in open source code.

Hence the question:

**What are the practical or technical benefits of using the `$inject` property form?**

From the top of my head I came up with two, and they don't look very legit:

- Creating instances of `MyStuff` directly:

  `new MyStuff(someOtherDependency).foo(...);`
- Having function name in `console.log(myStuffInstance)`

Anything else I am missing?

Comment: It's recommended for readability, to keep a clear separation of concerns.

Comment: Just had someone's comment about ng-annotate (https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate), which is worth mentioning...

Comment: Yes, `ng-anotate` is used as a task to automate adding minification-friendly injection for production mode, so then you don't have to add either `['$scope', ..., function ($scope, ...]` or `myFactory.$inject['$scope, ...`. when build to production it adds minification friendly inject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate). If you are using build tool (you should), use the ng-annotate plugin with your build tool.

The main benefit of second approach is that it is module friendly.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor($q) {}
}

MyClass.$inject = ['$q']

module.exprots = MyClass
```

You can use it like normal class

```
const MyClass = require('./myclass')
const foo = new MyClass($q)
```

or give it to angular

```
angular.service('MyClass', MyClass)
```

You can't really do

```
module.exports = ['$q', MyClass]
```

because it will make `require('./myclass')` unusable outside of angular

---

But if you are not using module or OOP, first approach is easier

```
angular.service('MyClass', ['$q', function ($q) {}])
```

There is no need to make a class for it